# PhantomJS Record User Session Video

Tags: phantomjs, phantomjs-node

I'm developing an in-house solution to record the users sessions activity in the web pages visited by them. By activity I mean mouse movement and clicks.

I am already recording that info with the timestamp when the events happened  but I would like to know if there is a way to capture a video (or a sequence of images) using PhantomJS of the web pages when they are being visited.

I thought about capture a screenshot every amount of time...but how can I get the actual portion of the page that the user is viewing?

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: PhantomJS can capture images of a page, but your pages are visited by other people with other browsers. Do you plan to repeat their actions in PhantomJS?

Comment: @Vaviloff yes, that exactly what I intend to do. :-)